# Unable to load C++ DLL in .NET with /OPT:NOREF

Tags: c++, .net, interop

I am trying to invoke some functions of a C++ native in VB.NET but I have a strange problem. If I compile my C++ DLL in Release mode it works, if I compile it in Debug mode it throws an error like:

> Unable to load DLL 'DllName.dll': The parameter is incorrect.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

I thought in the beginning that could a problem with MSVCR100D.dll that is referenced in Debug DLLs but that was not the case.

Instead I discovered that if I compile my C++ DLL using option `/OPT:NOREF` it does not work; if instead I compile it using `/OPT:REF` it works.

I am a bit lost now, do you know what could be the problem in this case?

Comment: Some Windows API function fails when the DLL is getting loaded.  You'll need to use an unmanaged debugger to find out why.  Start by debugging the DllMain() function.

Comment: @Hans Passant I tried to debug it natively, but it seems that the exception is thrown by system KernelBase.dll and I have no access to that code.

Comment: You can safely assume that the bug isn't located in kernelbase.dll.  Be sure to have the Microsoft Symbol Server configured properly, post the call stack.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to made the dll fail at the same model.